# Отправка post запроса к wordpress из android studio. Как реализовать? Предоставляю пример кода как работало на python

Tags: android, python

Писалась программа на python, я же сейчас переношу её потихоньку на android. Сейчас нужно передать post запрос к wordpress.

То что успешно работает на python -

```py
        s = requests.Session()
        data = {"log": self.login, "pwd": self.password}
        url = "https://wordpress.com/wp-login.php"
        s.post(url, data=data)
        massiv_cokies = s.cookies
        kol_vo_cokies = len(massiv_cokies)
```

Всё достаточно просто и понятно. Отправляется пост запрос с логином и паролем пользователя и берётся количество строк куки, которое возвращает wordpress.

Как реализовать тоже самое на android studio? Или возможно как подключить именно сам python файл к android studio? Так как в нём видел что можно создавать питон файл. Но как его интегрировать ума не приложу .. и связать с переменными из android studio. Это был конечно самый идеальный вариант решения проблемы.

Помогите кто чем сможет! ) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть стандартные штуки типа `AsyncTask`. Но советую сразу использовать [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). В интернете куча примеров([Тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/314028/) и [Тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/retrofit.php)).
В твоем случае сначала нужно создать модель отправляемых данных:

```
#Auth.class
public class Auth{
    @SerializedName("log")
    private String log;
    @SerializedName("pwd")
    private String pwd;

    public Auth(String log, String pwd){
        this.log = log;
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }
}
```

Далее нужно создать интерфейс описания запросов и класc билдера:

```
#JSONPlaceHolderApi.class
public interface JSONPlaceHolderApi{
    @POST("wp-login.php") 
    Call<Integer> getCookies(@Body Auth data) #Указываем, что в ответ вернется Integer, а в теле отправится наш созданный класс Auth с его данными
}

#NetworkService.class
public class NetworkService {
    private static NetworkService mInstance;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://wordpress.com"; #адрес сервера
    private Retrofit mRetrofit;

    private NetworkService() {
        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) #Используем json сериализатор
                .build();
    }

    public static NetworkService getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new NetworkService();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public JSONPlaceHolderApi getJSONApi() {
        return mRetrofit.create(JSONPlaceHolderApi.class);
    }
}
```

И наконец сам запрос:

```
NetworkService.getInstance()
    .getJSONApi()
    .login(new Auth("log", "pwd"))
    .enqueue(new Callback<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Integer> call, @NonNull Response<Integer> response) {
           if(response.isSuccessful()){
               #Успешно
               Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response.body()));                      
           }else{
               #Сервер вернул ошибку                         
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Integer> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
           #Ошибка запроса
       }
    });
```

Ну и конечно нужно подключить retrofit к проекту:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
```

P.S. У вас в ответе, как я понял вернется массив `massiv_cokies`(У меня примере Integer). Поэтому вам нужно будет создать еще один класс модели и указать в запросе этот класс.